# JAVA: Finding the mean of an ArrayList Double

Tags: java, arraylist, double

I am trying to replicate this exact code replacing every instance of Integer with `Double` (not `double`), but keep getting type mismatch errors every time i try to do so... can anyone help?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Mean {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            Integer input = in.nextInt();
            numbers.add(input);
        }
        in.close();

        Integer sum = 0;
        for (Integer element : numbers) {
            sum += element;
        }
        System.out.println(sum / numbers.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you also do "Double input = in.nextDouble();"?

Comment: which error are you getting? please, post the exception trace.

Comment: Why don't you show us the code where you replaced `Integer`s with `Double`s? The posted original code is irrelevant to your question...

Comment: I thought I would show this code because it functions exactly how I would like it to

Answer (score 3):

You need to change what your [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is looking for, I'd also recommend using the interface [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and the diamond operator. Finally, closing a `Scanner` on `System.in` is always a bad idea. So,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); // <-- List and Diamond Operator
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (in.hasNextDouble()) { // <-- hasNextDouble()
        Double input = in.nextDouble(); // <-- get the next double
        numbers.add(input);
    }
    // in.close(); // <-- Wraps System.in, don't do this.

    Double sum = 0.0; // <-- initialize as double
    for (Double element : numbers) {
        sum += element; // <-- add the values.
    }
    System.out.println(sum / numbers.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one line that causes a problem, and that is

```
Double sum = 0;
```

This is since the literal `0` is treated as an `int` by Java, which can automatically either be boxed to an `Integer` or widened to a `double`, but not both to make it a `Double`.

Just change the declaration to a double literal:

```
Double sum = 0d;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reps to comment on Elliot's post. I just added an end condition to his code, so that we can prevent an infinite loop and once you type "end", the process of taking input finishes and it computes the result.

```
package Mean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Mean {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); // <-- List and Diamond Operator
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNextDouble()) { // <-- hasNextDouble()
            Double input = in.nextDouble(); // <-- get the next double
            numbers.add(input);
            //if (numbers.equals("end")) (revision :  unnecessary, type any non double to stop loop)
            //    break;
            }

        } 
        // in.close(); // <-- Wraps System.in, don't do this.

        Double sum = 0.0; // <-- initialize as double
        for (Double element : numbers) {
            sum += element; // <-- add the values.
        }
        System.out.println(sum / numbers.size());

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Numbers will never equal "end", and as soon as a non double is input the `hasNextDouble()` will return false.

Comment: How will `List<Double> numbers` equal the `String` "end"? What platform are you using?

Comment: Hello, I just got the mistake. Nice finding. I didn't know it before. Rep added!!